# exception is happening and I don't no why

Tags: java, sql

I keep getting this exception. I want to insert using a query into a table called Toy.

It's in this order as below:

`Toy ID`, `Toy Name`, `age`, `price(as currency data type)`, `color`

Exception: ***invalid character value for cast***

```
import java.sql.*;

public class market{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Thekr\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Market.accdb");
    Statement stmt = c. createStatement();

    String query4= "INSERT INTO Toy VALUES (6,'JB Truck',3,20.00,'Yellow')";//here is where the exception is happening the data type of each column: integer,string,integer,currency data type that I dont know what is it,string

    stmt.executeUpdate(query4); 

    // the excepting is :
    // Exception in thread "main" net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException:
    // > UCAExc:::5.0.0-SNAPSHOT data exception: invalid character value for
    // > cast   at
    // > net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessStatement.java:230)
    // >    at market.main(market.java:11) Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException:
    // > data exception: invalid character value for cast   at
    //   > org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)    at
    //   > org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)    at
    //   > org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)    at
    // > org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)    at
    // > net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ExecuteUpdate.executeWrapped(ExecuteUpdate.java:65)
    // >    at
    // > net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.executeBase(AbstractExecute.java:264)
    //   >  at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ExecuteUpdate.execute(ExecuteUpdate.java:48)
    //   >  at
    //   > net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessStatement.java:228)
    //   >  ... 1 more Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception:
    // > invalid character value for cast   at
    //   > org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)     at
    //   > org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)     at
    //   > org.hsqldb.Scanner.convertToNumber(Unknown Source)   at
    //   > org.hsqldb.types.NumberType.convertToType(Unknown Source)    at
    //   > org.hsqldb.StatementDML.getInsertData(Unknown Source)    at
    //   > org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)     at
    //   > org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)     at
    //   > org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)  at
    //   > org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)    at
    //   > org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)   ... 7 more
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what was causing the Exception, ucanaccsess does not support a direct insertion of data,so you need to specify the column of the inserted data so the only change to my code will be :

```
  String query4="INSERT INTO Toy(ToyID,ToyName,Age,Price,Color) VALUES (6,'JB Truck',3,20.00,'Yellow')";
```